# Can't understand why if statement is running code for True test result

Tags: c#

I have an IF statement that is supposed to make sure the `TextBox1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text` do not match or are not blank. If they don't match or are not blank then it is supposed to assign the text in the boxes to two string variable. What I can't figure out is why when I leave the two textboxes blank the true statement still fires.

```
if ((tbStartBreak2.Text != tbEndBreak2.Text) || (tbStartBreak2.Text == "" && tbEndBreak2.Text == ""))
{
  sb2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
  se2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
}
```

Comment: *"...why when I leave the two textboxes blank the true statement still fires"* ...because that's exactly what the second condition says?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two conditions in your if statement:

```
if ((tbStartBreak2.Text != tbEndBreak2.Text) || (tbStartBreak2.Text == "" && tbEndBreak2.Text == ""))
```

The first one checks to make sure they don't match (so, good).  The second checks to make sure that they **are** blank (so, bad).  You want this:

```
if ((tbStartBreak2.Text != tbEndBreak2.Text) || (tbStartBreak2.Text != "" && tbEndBreak2.Text != ""))
```

Also, what are you trying to do?  The second condition is the only one you need if you really want them not to match OR not be blank - because the only time this will be false is if they are both blank.

Comment: Thanks, been working on this script for almost 20 hours I think the lack of sleep is finally getting to me.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "OR textbox are blank", you need "OR textbox are not blank"

```
    if ((tbStartBreak2.Text != tbEndBreak2.Text) || (tbStartBreak2.Text != "" && tbEndBreak2.Text != ""))
    {
        sb2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
        se2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
    }
```

As a side note, I'd replace `""` with `string.Empty` for readability.

```
    if ((tbStartBreak2.Text != tbEndBreak2.Text) || (tbStartBreak2.Text != string.Empty && tbEndBreak2.Text != string.Empty))
    {
        sb2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
        se2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
    }
```

And for even more readability, you can extract these big conditions

```
    if (TextboxesDoNotMatch() || TextboxesAreNotEmpty())
    {
        sb2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
        se2 = tbStartBreak2.Text;
    }

private bool TextboxesDoNotMatch()
{
    return tbStartBreak2.Text != tbEndBreak2.Text;
}

private bool TextboxesAreNotEmpty()
{
    return tbStartBreak2.Text != string.Empty && tbEndBreak2.Text != string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to return that they are NOT blank then you need to do this

```
(tbStartBreak2.Text != "" && tbEndBreak2.Text != "")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an OR between both conditions so when both are empty the second part will be true  regardless the first part

> (tbStartBreak2.Text == "" && tbEndBreak2.Text == "")